# How to color each letter text in Phaser.js?

Tags: javascript, text, phaser

I have a text created with text object (game.add.text) and I would like to color each letter differently if that is possible.
If not, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for this was added in Phaser 2.1.2. Please see the [Text.addColor](http://docs.phaser.io/Phaser.Text.html#addColor) method.